# How to get parametrs to BackingBean from jsf page in <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My xhtml:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{c.voices}" var="v"> 
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{AddNote.handleFileUpload}"
            converterMessage="converterMessage"
            mode="advanced"  
            update="messages"  
            sizeLimit="100000"                                                 
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/">
        </p:fileUpload>  
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>                                     
    </h:form> 
</ui:repeat>
```

My BackingBean:

```
 public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    //int v.id= here i need to know the v.id value from ui:repeater
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

**c.voices** is list of objects. Every object have attribute **id**. I need to know the **id** in **handelFileUpload** how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply put `v.id` in an hidden field :

Your xhtml:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{c.voices}" var="v">
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="vid" value="#{v.id}" />
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{AddNote.handleFileUpload}"
            converterMessage="converterMessage"
            mode="advanced"
            update="messages"
            sizeLimit="100000"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/">
        </p:fileUpload>
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
    </h:form> 
</ui:repeat>
```

And then get it back in the bean using `FacesContext` :

Your BackingBean:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    request.getParameter("vid"); // <= Here you are!
}
```

**UPDATE**

As stated in the comments each iteration will have it's own `<h:form` with it's own `<input type="hidden" name="vid"`. When a file is uploaded the `handleFileUpload` will be fired with the data of the enclosing form, thus the `vid` parameter will be sent with the correct `#{v.id}`

**UPDATE 2**

As BalusC commented you should preferably get `vid` parameter this way :

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .getRequestParameterMap().get("vid") // <= Here you are!
}
```

Comment: That's not going to work because of iteration: there won't be one hidden input, but a bunch of those.

Comment: Look carefully, the hidden input is in the `<h:form` itself nested into the `<ui:repeat` which means that you'll have `i` forms with `i` hidden inputs so each `<p:fileUpload` will send it's own form with it's own hidden input so yes it will work. Tested and working.

Comment: Agreed, I oversaw multiple forms. Could you edit the answer so that I could reverse my vote?

Comment: Updated with some clarifications

Comment: Your welcome, don't forget to mark the answer as _accepted answer_ as explained in the faq : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Technically a good answer, but a little word of advice: `javax.servlet.*` imports in JSF artifacts must be avoided to all extent as they indicate tight coupling or just simply a "clumsy" approach (read: there's a big chance that JSF already offers more clean API-provided ways which you should use instead). In this case, you should use `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` instead. Or, when the bean is request scoped, a `@ManagedProperty("#{param.vid}")` on the target property.