# Custom scope of a ManagedBean in JSF2.0 with PrimeFaces 3.5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Following is my requirement-
[image]

Here I have a `p:panelGrid` which can add & delete the row of table. The grid contains some `p:inputText` and various other PrimeFaces components along with a `p:fileUpload` component in each row. The component `p:fileUpload` is set with `mode="advanced" auto="true"` attributes, which automatically uploads the file and hide itself after completing the successful upload.

The whole `p:panelGrid` is in `@ViewScoped`, hence working fine. I kept `p:fileUpload` component in `@RequestScoped` since for each upload request it has to upload the file but after adding new row, the previous state is not persisted anymore. so the `p:fileUpload` is starting visible in previous rows also. That's what I don't want. Do I need to write any custom  scope for it?
Below is the view-|

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="agentForm" header="#{msg.AGENTS_INFORMATION}"
        style="overflow:auto;  margin-bottom: 2px">
        <div align="center" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 2px">
            <ui:repeat value="#{agent.scenarioList}" var="c">
                <p:panelGrid>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="ipaddress" value="#{c.machineIpAddress}"
                                style="width:90%">
                                <p:watermark for="ipaddress" value="#{msg.MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{c.machineUsername}"
                                style="width:90%">
                                <p:watermark for="username" value="#{msg.MACHINE_USERNAME}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:password id="passwd" value="#{c.machinePassword}">
                                <p:watermark for="passwd" value="#{msg.MACHINE_PASSWORD}" />
                            </p:password>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="fileUpload">
                            <p:fileUpload rendered="#{!fileUploadController.hidden}"
                                label="Upload Script" style="font-size: 100% !important;"
                                showButtons="false"
                                fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"
                                mode="advanced" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000"
                                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(py|txt)$/"
                                update="fileUpload, outPanel, :message" />
                            <p:outputPanel id="outPanel">
                            <!-- Below outputLabel will be linked to uploaded file, so that User can see the file -->
                            <p:outputLabel style="cursor: pointer" value="View uploded Script"
                                    label="View Script" rendered="#{fileUploadController.hidden}" />
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="testname" value="#{c.testName}"
                                style="width:90%">
                                <p:watermark for="testname" value="#{msg.TEST_NAME}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:spinner id="threads" value="#{c.threads}" min="1" max="500"
                                size="8">
                                <p:tooltip for="threads" value="#{msg.TEST_NAME}"
                                    showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" />
                            </p:spinner>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkSelected" value="#{c.selected}">
                                <p:tooltip for="chkSelected" value="#{msg.CHECKBOX}"
                                    showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" />
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </ui:repeat>
            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.ADD_IT}"
                        update=":message, agentForm"
                        actionListener="#{agent.addComponent()}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.DELETE_IT}"
                        update=":message, agentForm"
                        actionListener="#{agent.deleteComponent()}" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>
        </div>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

My managed bean which is in `@ViewScoped` look like this-

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.ravij.performance.model.Scenario;
@ManagedBean(name = "agent")
@ViewScoped
public class AgentInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<Scenario> scenarioList;
    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean() {
        this.scenarioList = new ArrayList<Scenario>();
        this.scenarioList.add(new Scenario());
    }
    public void addComponent() {
        if (this.scenarioList != null) {
            this.scenarioList.add(new Scenario());
        } else {
            this.initBean();
        }
    }
    public void deleteComponent() {
        List<Scenario> itemsToDelete = new ArrayList<Scenario>();
        if (this.scenarioList != null) {
            for (Scenario b : this.scenarioList) {
                if (b.isSelected()) {
                    itemsToDelete.add(b);
                }
            }
            this.scenarioList.removeAll(itemsToDelete);
        }
    }
    public List<Scenario> getScenarioList() {
        return scenarioList;
    }
    public void setScenarioList(List<Scenario> scenarioList) {
        this.scenarioList = scenarioList;
    }
}
```

The Scenario object contains all the information of a row. Below is the code-

```
package org.ravij.performance.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Scenario implements Serializable {
    private String machineIpAddress;
    private String machineUsername;
    private String machinePassword;
    private String uploadedFilePath;
    private String testName;
    private int threads = 1;
    private boolean selected = false;

    //Below are the getters and setter w.r.t all the above variables
    //I am not putting it, to make the code short
}
```

The managed bean `FileUploadController` is in `@RequestScoped`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply keep your `hidden` attribute with the other values in your `@ViewScoped` bean. Your current code has a single `hidden` attribute shared with all your `<p:fileUpload` components which is probably not what you want.

The behavior looks good because you are only updating the current `fileUpload` but according to your code all the others `<p:fileUpload` component are supposed to be hidden.

You should also put your `<h:form` into your `<ui:repeat` so that you can know the current line which is concerned by the file being uploaded by putting something like an index (which you can get from the `<ui:repeat` using `varStatus` attribute) or any other identifier to match the current line in an hidden input.

From `#{fileUploadController.upload}` the easiest manner to get the hidden parameter is to get the response from `FacesContext` as explained here : [How to get parametrs to BackingBean from jsf page in <ui:repeat>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821929/how-to-get-parametrs-to-backingbean-from-jsf-page-in-uirepeat/15822733#15822733)

**UPDATE**

It was a bit harder than expected, the problem is that `<p:fileUpload` will send everything in the enclosing form (didn't try to play with `process` attribute) and thus it will be hard to know what row is concerned by the file upload.

Also I didn't knew that you couldn't put `<h:form` in your `<ui:repeat` but the behavior of your delete button is blocking as it expects to get everything in one form.

I made a working POC using dialog to put the fileupload outside, here is how :

The trivial Scenario.java :

```
public class Scenario implements Serializable {

    private String machineIpAddress;
    private String machineUsername;
    private String machinePassword;
    private String uploadedFilePath;
    private String testName;
    private int threads = 1;
    private boolean selected = false;
    private boolean hidden = false; // This is new

    // + Getters/Setters
}
```

A few changes in the AgentInfo.java :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "agent")
@ViewScoped
public class AgentInfo implements Serializable {

    private List<Scenario> scenarioList;

    private Scenario currentScenario; // This is new

    // I removed the @PostConstruct which I rarely use

    public void addComponent() {
        if (this.scenarioList != null) {
            this.scenarioList.add(new Scenario());
        }
    }

    public void deleteComponent() {
        if (this.scenarioList == null) {
            return;
        }

        List<Scenario> itemsToDelete = new ArrayList<Scenario>();

        for (Scenario scenario : this.scenarioList) {
            if (scenario.isSelected()) {
                itemsToDelete.add(scenario);
            }
        }

        this.scenarioList.removeAll(itemsToDelete);
    }

    // This is new, it must be called before opening the upload dialog
    // in order to keep a pointer on the current scenario you are working on
    public void prepareUpload(Scenario scenario) {
        this.currentScenario = scenario;
    }

    // I put the upload method here
    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        // Do what you need to do here
        this.currentScenario.setHidden(true);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("uploadDialogWidget.hide()");
    }

    public List<Scenario> getScenarioList() {
        if (this.scenarioList == null) {
            this.scenarioList = new ArrayList<Scenario>();
            this.scenarioList.add(new Scenario());
        }

        return scenarioList;
    }

    public void setScenarioList(List<Scenario> scenarioList) {
        this.scenarioList = scenarioList;
    }

    public Scenario getCurrentScenario() {
        return currentScenario;
    }

    public void setCurrentScenario(Scenario currentScenario) {
        this.currentScenario = currentScenario;
    }
}
```

The most changes are in the view, I put a `<h:commandButton` to open the dialog in the form. I also added the dialog, and added the `redisplay` attribute for your password fields (which is necessary to have if you want to keep the value after form submission).
Note that I removed references to a component with `message` id which was not gave, don't forget to reintroduce it.
the .xhtml :

```
<h:form id="agentForm">
    <p:panel header="#{msg.AGENTS_INFORMATION}"
        style="overflow:auto;  margin-bottom: 2px">
        <div align="center" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 2px">
            <ui:repeat value="#{agent.scenarioList}" var="c">
                <p:panelGrid>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="ipaddress" value="#{c.machineIpAddress}"
                                style="width:90%">
                                <p:watermark for="ipaddress" value="#{msg.MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{c.machineUsername}"
                                style="width:90%">
                                <p:watermark for="username" value="#{msg.MACHINE_USERNAME}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:password id="passwd" value="#{c.machinePassword}" redisplay="true">
                                <p:watermark for="passwd" value="#{msg.MACHINE_PASSWORD}" />
                            </p:password>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="fileUpload">
                            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n" value="Upload"
                                             actionListener="#{agent.prepareUpload(c)}"
                                             update=":uploadDialog"
                                             oncomplete="uploadDialogWidget.show()"
                                             rendered="#{!c.hidden}" />
                            <p:outputPanel id="outPanel">
                            <!-- Below outputLabel will be linked to uploaded file, so that User can see the file -->
                            <p:outputLabel style="cursor: pointer" value="View uploded Script"
                                    rendered="#{c.hidden}" />
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText id="testname" value="#{c.testName}"
                                style="width:90%">
                                <p:watermark for="testname" value="#{msg.TEST_NAME}" />
                            </p:inputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:spinner id="threads" value="#{c.threads}" min="1" max="500"
                                size="8">
                                <p:tooltip for="threads" value="#{msg.TEST_NAME}"
                                    showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" />
                            </p:spinner>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkSelected" value="#{c.selected}">
                                <p:tooltip for="chkSelected" value="#{msg.CHECKBOX}"
                                    showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide" />
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </ui:repeat>
            <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.ADD_IT}" update="agentForm"
                                     actionListener="#{agent.addComponent()}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.DELETE_IT}" update="agentForm"
                        actionListener="#{agent.deleteComponent()}" />
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>
        </div>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="uploadDialog" widgetVar="uploadDialogWidget" header="File upload">
    <h:form rendered="#{!empty agent.currentScenario}">
        <p:fileUpload
            label="Upload Script" style="font-size: 100% !important;"
            showButtons="false"
            fileUploadListener="#{agent.upload}"
            mode="advanced" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000"
            allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(py|txt)$/"
            update=":agentForm">
        </p:fileUpload>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="uploadDialogWidget.hide();" onstart="return false;" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

You should consider to move from `<p:panelGrid` to a `<p:dataTable` which has a built in mechanism to work with row selection.

Comment: Thank you...Can you please elaborate a little bit more about `hidden` fields in `@ViewScoped` bean. My bean `contains` a list of `user` object. It's traditional and simple enough.
Can you provide the modified code based on my view?

Comment: Sure, add the `addComponent()` and `deleteComponent()` code from your `agent` bean to your question and I'll update my answer with a working example.

Comment: Updated the question with required code. Please have a look into it.

Comment: Updated, don't hesitate to comment if something is missing for you. It's not _exactly_ what you wanted to but I hope it will fulfill your needs

Comment: You did the magic... Thank you. working fine.. cool. thank you so much. I did a little change in `fileUpload`. I added `oncomplete="uploadDialogWidget.hide();"` and removed the same from bean. But your hack was awesome. Having a `currentScenario` did all the wonder.